# Vuex persist losses data after refresh

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex

Im tying to save some data which needs to be persistent after a page reload. I stumbled across Vuex. I managed to get it working in a Javascript only project, but for some reason I dont get it to work in TypeScript. After a refresh the data uses the default values instead of data which was assigned before the page refresh.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'
import LanguageEntry from '../classes/LanguageEntry'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export interface State {
  IsDark: boolean;
  CurrentLanuage: string;
  LanguageValues: Array<LanguageEntry>;
}

export default new Vuex.Store<State>({
  state: {
    IsDark: false,
    CurrentLanuage: "DE",
    LanguageValues: Array<LanguageEntry>(),
  },
  plugins: [new VuexPersistence().plugin],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a popular plugin to persist data [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) after refresh which I noticed today has been recently updated than yours.

I use it in the /route index.js like:

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';

export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      // example
    clients,
    auth: authentication,
    },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  })

  return store
}
```